# Удаление пробелов

Tags: php

Нужна функция удаления пробелов на php, но не Trim. Т.к. она должна удалять пробелы не только по краям, но и в теле текста.
Т.е. вот так, до удаления:

`Audi, bmw em [ Q7 ]`

После удаления пробелов:

`Audi,bmw em[Q7]`

Т.е. она должна удалять пробелы только в скобках `[]` и после запятой, в остальных случаях оставлять пробелы.

Comment: ling, если внутри выражения есть "", то сервер выдает 500 еррор, как избежать ошибки не убирая "" внутри текста?

Comment: Все, помощь больше не нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace("/\s*([,\[\]])\s*/", "$1", "Audi, bmw em [ Q7 ]");
```

или

```
$str = preg_replace("/\s*([,\{\}])\s*/", "$1", "Audi, bmw em [ Q7 ]");
```

Comment: Если не сложно, то как будет выглядеть код удаления пробелов только сначала скобки [ и в конце ]?
Т.е. до удаления:
Audi, bmw em [ Q7, 124 ]
После удаления:
Audi,bmw em[Q7, 124]

Comment: В вашем примере пробелы удаляются с обеих сторон от скобок. Вы имеете в виду, чтобы удалять пробелы вокруг запятых, кроме тех, которые внутри скобок?

Comment: Давайте я покажу еще один пример. До удаления: Audi, bmw em { q7-d: u; c : #1; b: 0; -m-o-s: n 0 1; } После удаления: Audi,bmw em{q7-d: u; c : #1; b: 0; -m-o-s: n 0 1;}

Comment: Ок, объясняю, что делает мой preg_replace. Он убирает пробелы до и после знаков `,[]`. Если нужны еще и `{}`, добавьте их в набор. Если внутри скобок встретятся запятые, пробелы будут обрезаны и вокруг них. Не понимаю проблемы, простите.

Comment: именно так и работает приведенное выще регулярное выражение.. Только вот фигурные скобки на квадратные замените )

Comment: Гуглите regexp. Не, ну правда же.

Comment: Да, извините, это я что-то протупил, не знаю почему. Если внутри выражения есть "", то сервер выдает 500 еррор, как избежать ошибки не убирая "" внутри текста?

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет функция [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
$str = str_replace(" ", "", "Audi [ Q7 ]");
```

Comment: Чуть-чуть дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'Audi, bmw em [ Q7 ]';
$newString = str_replace(array(', ', '[ ', ' ]', ' ['), '', $string);
```

Comment: этот код удаляет  запятые и скобки, при этом пробелы остаются

Comment: Вообще-то логика функции "Заменить (Что, На что, Где)", так что она меняет элементы массива на пустоту в заданной строке.